# ¿Como modelar plataforma para compartir coche en JPA?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Soy novato y a modo de práctica estoy empezando un proyecto basado en una plataforma para compartir coche. Dispongo de las siguientes entidades: coche, usuario y trayecto.

Tengo la relación y las anotaciones JPA entre coche y usuario definida. Un usuario puede tener varios coches y un coche lleva únicamente a un usuario (su dueño), cosa que hago con una relación bidireccional OnetoMany de usuario a coche y otra ManytoOne desde coche a usuario.

Ahora bien, si desde la entidad Trayecto quiero poder acceder al usuario titular de ese trayecto y el coche con el que se realiza dicho trayecto...¿cómo puedo modelar esa relación? Un trayecto tendrá un único usuario titular (el creador de dicho trayecto) y un único vehículo pero no acabo de ver como modelarlo. ¿Alguien podría echarme un cable?

Saludos y mil gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Por un lado, a nivel `mysql`, ya tenes que tener tu tabla, `trayecto` mínimamente con los siguientes campos: `id, id_coche, id_usuario`.

- Relación:

`trayecto` `many-to-one` `coche`

`trayecto` `many-to-one` `usuario`

O sea, las **claves foráneas** `id_coche` e `id_usuario` en tabla `trayecto`

Ahora en el **mapeo** (archivo xml) de `hibernate` debes indicar la relación:

- archivo Trayecto.hbm.xml:

```
<many-to-one name="coche" class="nombrePaquete.Coche">
<column name="id_coche" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one name="usuario" class="nombrePaquete.Usuario">
<column name="id_usuario" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

`name` es el nombre de la propiedad o atributo en tu clase de java.

`column name` es el nombre de la propiedad o atributo en tabla mysql.

Nota: solo mostré el mapeo de las calves foráneas, falta el código de la clave primaria y de las propiedades (si es que hay).